# "Beautify" Java console output

Tags: java, console, output

I would like to beautify my edition in the console.
How can I write the whole thing now like in a table?
I've tried counting with spaces, but as the values change, it's very bad.Do you have a good idea how I could beautify the issue that stands between them?

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j80o3.png)

My code:

```
 private static void berechneVerbrauch(Tankbeleg[] tanken) {
        System.out.print("Datum" + " KM-Stand" + " Liter" + " Preis" + " Verbrauch");
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tanken.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(tanken[i].datum + " " + tanken[i].kmStand + " " + tanken[i].getankteLiter + " " + tanken[i].literPreis+ " " );
            System.out.println(" ");

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Best regards
Michael

**EDIT**

[Console output with \t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIyQA.png)

```
private static void berechneVerbrauch(Tankbeleg[] tanken) {
        System.out.print("Datum" + "\tKM-Stand" + "\tLiter" + "\tPreis" + "\tVerbrauch");
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tanken.length; i++) {
            //System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s", tanken[i].datum, tanken[i].kmStand, tanken[i].getankteLiter, tanken[i].literPreis);
            System.out.print(tanken[i].datum + "\t" + tanken[i].kmStand + "\t" + tanken[i].getankteLiter + "\t" + tanken[i].literPreis+ "\t" );
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.out.printf()` . printf is formatted printing, so you can declare how many spaces you want each variable to have to it, truncating or extending the variable as desired. See the [tutorials for printf()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0200__printf-Method.htm) to learn how to use it.

In your case, something like this might look good for the header:

```
System.out.printf("%10s %8s %5s %5s %9s", "Datum", "KM-Stand", "Liter", "Preis", "Verbrauch");
```

And for the data lines:

```
System.out.printf("%10s %8s %5s %5s", tanken[i].datum, tanken[i].kmStand, tanken[i].getankteLiter, tanken[i].literPreis );
```

I wrote a main method like this to emulate the code so that I could see the formatting

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.printf("%10s %8s %5s %5s %9s", "Datum", "KM-Stand", "Liter", "Preis", "Verbrauch");
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%10s %8s %5s %5s", args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] );
        System.out.println(" ");

    }
}
```

:: output ::

```
$ java Test 20.05.2010 30000 20 30
     Datum KM-Stand Liter Preis Verbrauch 
20.05.2010    30000    20    30 
20.05.2010    30000    20    30 
20.05.2010    30000    20    30 
20.05.2010    30000    20    30 

$ java Test alpha beta cala baza
     Datum KM-Stand Liter Preis Verbrauch 
     alpha     beta  cala  baza 
     alpha     beta  cala  baza 
     alpha     beta  cala  baza 
     alpha     beta  cala  baza
```

You can toy with the `printf` options to make them left aligned or fill in with other characters besides spaces, it's a really useful tool

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spaces you can play with tab \t

Comment: Thank you! Please have a look at my new edit. 
With \t It looks better but is not optimal yet.

Comment: Double the tabs then , try this one

"\t\tKM-Stand" 

"\t\t" + tanken[i].getankteLiter